# Forcing ignore validation for string Primary Key not working in Laravel 8 to update data

Tags: laravel

i need a help with my laravel app. i have a table with this structure:

```
Schema::create('kliens', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('KlienUIC', 10)->primary();
            $table->string('NamaLahir', 50);
            $table->string('NamaPanggilan', 10)->nullable();
            $table->date('TanggalLahir');
            $table->string('KategoriKlien', 10);
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('StafPendampingId');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('StafPendampingId')->references('StafId')->on('stafs')->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
```

and the model is:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'KlienUIC';
public $incrementing = false;
protected $keyType = 'string';

use HasFactory;

protected $fillable = ['KlienUIC', 'NamaLahir', 'NamaPanggilan', 'TanggalLahir', 'KategoriKlien', 'StafPendampingId'];
```

i want to update my existing data but it keeps give me `The klienuic has already been taken.` error message when i don't change my `KlienUIC` value.

this is my update method and the validation (with some other attempts to force the ignore validation, and they all still error):

```
public function update(Request $request, Klien $klien)
    {
        $validatedData = Validator::make($request, [
            // 'klienuic' => Rule::unique('kliens', 'KlienUIC', $klien->KlienUIC)->ignore($klien->KlienUIC, 'KlienUIC'),
            // 'klienuic' => ['required','size:10',Rule::unique('kliens', 'KlienUIC')->ignore($klien->KlienUIC, 'KlienUIC')],
            // 'klienuic' => ['required','size:10',Rule::unique('kliens', 'KlienUIC')->ignore($id)],
            // 'klienuic' => 'required|size:10|unique:kliens,KlienUIC,'.$this->klien->KlienUIC,
            // 'klienuic' => ['required','size:10',Rule::unique('kliens', 'KlienUIC')->ignore($this->klien)],
            // 'klienuic' => 'required|size:10|unique:kliens,KlienUIC,'.$klien->KlienUIC,
            // 'klienuic' => ['required','size:10',Rule::unique('kliens')->ignore($klien->KlienUIC)],
            // 'klienuic' => ['required','size:10',Rule::unique('kliens', 'KlienUIC')->ignore($klien->KlienUIC, 'KlienUIC')],
            'klienuic' => ['required','size:10','unique:kliens,KlienUIC'],
            'namalahir' => 'required|min:3|max:50',
            'namapanggilan' => 'min:3|max:10',
            'tanggallahir' => 'required',
            'kategoriklien' => 'required',
            'stafpendamping' => 'required'
        ]);

        Klien::where('KlienUIC', $klien->KlienUIC)
               ->update([
                   'KlienUIC' => $validatedData['klienuic'],
                   'NamaLahir' => $validatedData['namalahir'],
                   'NamaPanggilan' => $validatedData['namapanggilan'],
                   'TanggalLahir' => $validatedData['tanggallahir'],
                   'KategoriKlien' => $validatedData['kategoriklien'],
                   'StafPendampingId' => $validatedData['stafpendamping']
               ]);

        return redirect('/kliens')->with('success', 'Data klien berhasil diperbaharui.');
    }
```

i'm using Laravel `8.83.10`. thank you all

[the error for ignore 'KlienUIC' column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0w1H.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to update the primary key which isn't gonna work, primary keys usually don't get updated.

Besides that you can use the model that is injected as a parameter to update the data instead of using the `Klien::where()` which returns a `QueryBuilder`

```php
$klien->fill([
    'NamaLahir' => $validatedData['namalahir'],
    'NamaPanggilan' => $validatedData['namapanggilan'],
    'TanggalLahir' => $validatedData['tanggallahir'],
    'KategoriKlien' => $validatedData['kategoriklien'],
    'StafPendampingId' => $validatedData['stafpendamping']
]);
$klien->save();
```

Edit:

```
public function update(Request $request, Klien $klien)
    {
        $validatedData = Validator::make($request, [
            'namalahir' => 'required|min:3|max:50',
            'namapanggilan' => 'min:3|max:10',
            'tanggallahir' => 'required',
            'kategoriklien' => 'required',
            'stafpendamping' => 'required'
        ]);

        $klien->fill([
            'NamaLahir' => $validatedData['namalahir'],
            'NamaPanggilan' => $validatedData['namapanggilan'],
            'TanggalLahir' => $validatedData['tanggallahir'],
            'KategoriKlien' => $validatedData['kategoriklien'],
            'StafPendampingId' => $validatedData['stafpendamping']
        ]);
        $klien->save();

        return redirect('/kliens')->with('success', 'Data klien berhasil diperbaharui.');
    }
```

Comment: thank you for telling me to avoid updating the primary keys, but unfortunately the error is still the same with your suggestion code. i also tried to erase my previous where() to update to primary keys, but still have the same error

Comment: Updated my answer with a suggestion for the update function

Comment: thank you so much for your help, i think something's wrong with my controller, i have to say that every time i clicked my save button, i can't find the update statement for the transaction.
```POST /klien/create
EditKlienController@store```
the finding:
```SELECT count(*) as aggregate FROM 'kliens' WHERE 'KlienUIC' = 'KLIE123456'```
that's the query from the form's POST method. it also has no destination table when i inspect my app with clockwork. i should try fix my controller. thank you once again! i'll update if i found the solution later

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I have to create a resource controller for the `update()`. Previously, I did it within a non-resource controller. I think that's the problem. I have created my resource controller and my update works now.
I should avoid doing `update()` without a non-resource controller.